# How can iterate a JSON to create the body of a table - jQuery tmpl/template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to iterate a JSON variable to create a table using jQuery template/tmpl to do so, I've succeeded on iterating one-dimensional JSON but when trying to generate the table's body where you need to generate a two-dimensional iteration cell >inside> row, I couldn't do it.

Any help is profusely appreciated!

**My code:**

```js
//$("#blogPostTemplate").tmpl(blogPosts).appendTo("#blogPostContainer");
//  Grab this template   fill it with this data    append it to this div
var data = [{
  tableTitle: ["Stand With The Hammonds"],
  thead: [{
    header: 'H1'
  }, {
    header: 'H2'
  }, {
    header: 'H3'
  }],
  tbody: [
    [{
      col: 0
    }, {
      col: 1
    }, {
      col: 2
    }],
    [{
      col: 0
    }, {
      col: 1
    }, {
      col: 2
    }]
  ]
}];

$('#blogPostTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#blogPostContainer');
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
tbody,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
}
thead,
th {
  border: 1px solid #00F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>standwithrand</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="blogPostContainer"></div>
  <script id="blogPostTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <table>
      <h1>${tableTitle}</h1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {{each thead}}
          <th>${header}</th>{{/each}}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{each tbody}}
        <tr>
          <td>${col}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you have to iterate through each row to generate each cell, so you only need to get the row index to access to each one. You could use the next fragment to generate each row and each cell:

```
      <tbody>
        {{each(idx) tbody}}
        <tr>
          {{each tbody[idx]}}
            <td>${col}</td>
          {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
```

Cheers,
Jorge

Comment: Thanks, dude, it worked perfectly, I've been so eager trying to figure that out +1